# Why can't zsh execute command compdef?

Tags: zsh, ubuntu-18.04, kubectl

I have installed zsh and oh my zsh on Ubuntu 18.04. I would like to use autocompletion for kubectl. Therefore I have added `source <(kubectl completion zsh)` to my ~/.zshrc file.

On execution of this script zsh gets the following error:

```
complete:13: command not found: compdef
```

The kubectl documentation states that when one gets the error above, you should put the following on top of the .zshrc file:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

After doing this and restarting the terminal, I get the same error.

In a git-issue I found the following helped people with a common issue:

```
#This will perform chmod g-w for each file returned by compaudit to remove write access for group
compaudit | xargs -I % chmod g-w "%"
#This will perform chown to current user (Windows and Linux) for each file returned by compaudit
compaudit | xargs -I % chown $USER "%"
#Remove all dump files (which normally speed up initialization)
rm ~/.zcompdump*
#Regenerate completions file
compinit
```

zsh logs the following while running the script:

```
kubescript:12457: command not found: _bash_comp
```

Unfortunately this did not solve my problem. What else can I do to fix my issue? Or even still: what can I do to find out what is causing it?

Comment: Try this one https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339954/zsh-command-not-found-compinstall-compinit-compdef Some users suggest also that this error may occur if you have two different versions of zsh installed.

Comment: Unfortunately the suggested link does not help. And I am pretty sure I have only one version of zsh installed.

Comment: Did you try solutions from both answers ?

Comment: Yes I did. Both without a result.

Comment: It looks like this issue https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/125

Comment: It's exactly that. It seems there is no solution for now...

Answer (score 41):

I fixed the error by using the following code in .zshrc:

```
# K8s auto-complete
autoload -U +X compinit && compinit
source <(kubectl completion zsh)
```

You may also do it using [oh-my-zsh plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/kubectl/kubectl.plugin.zsh) if you use oh-my-zsh.

Answer (score 8):

For my OSX `10.15.7` I did something similar

```
vi ~/.zshrc

alias k=kubectl
autoload -U +X compinit && compinit
[[ /usr/local/bin/kubectl ]] && source <(kubectl completion zsh)
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and it was solved updating nvm

`$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash`

Comment: No difference here, though.

Comment: What is the relation to `nvm` here?

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this after installing the Angular CLI. Turns that Angular adds something into your `.zshrc` file.

If you recently installed Angular CLI, open `~/.zshrc` and remove the lines added by Angular CLI.

Comment: My `~/.zshrc` has this line `source <(ng completion script)`. It has a left angle bracket but no right angle bracket. Yesterday my terminal was blocked for hours from running commands because of this script. I commented out the line and now my terminal works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After trying lot of options and going through diff treads. It worked for me after running below command

```
autoload -Uz compinstall && compinstall
```

This configures the ~/.zshrc and initialize the compinit by adding these 2 below lines:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

and then run below sudo commands which mentioned in [link](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/zsh+compinit%3A+insecure+directories%2C+run+compaudit+for+list.)

```
$ sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/zsh
$ sudo chown -R root:staff /usr/local/share/zsh
$ compaudit | xargs chmod g-w
```

at last restart the terminal.

Hope this helps for someone.

Comment: I ran your suggested `autoload -Uz compinstall && compinstall` (following the bare minimum prompts until my `.zshrc` file had the 2 lines you mention), then restarted my terminal (I did not attempt running the sudo commands), and my problem was fixed. Interestingly, after restarting my terminal, I tried commenting out the `autoload -Uz compinit` and `compinit` lines in my `.zshrc` file and everything still worked as expected (even after terminal restarts)... so that initial `autoload -Uz compinstall && compinstall` command fixed my problem without needing the `~/.zshrc` changes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was fixed after re-installing oh-my-zsh:

1. Deleted my old version `rm -rf ~/.oh-my-zsh`
2. Installed from https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh

Answer (score 0):

I really tried every answer here, but nothing worked.

So, I tried this tutorial paying attention to the last observation:

*"Note: Make sure you add this snippet before any call to compdef else you will still see the error"*

I had a complete call from Terraform installation in my ~/.zshrc and ~/.bash_profile files.

https://thysmichels.com/2020/07/16/mac-solved-command-not-found-compdef/

Answer (score 0):

For me I had this line:

```
source ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh
```

In my `~/.zshrc` file. Which was trying to source the plugin before it is loaded by `plugins=(git)`

Removing that line fixed it for me.

If you have added the plugins and everything works well, One of the reasons is you may be trying to use the plugin before it is loaded. As in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is (also) faced after installing Angular CLI (Angular Version 14.x) and accepting addition of autocompletion for the cli commands. Snippet from .zshrc:

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
source <(ng completion script)
```

Commenting out the source line resolved the issue for me (macOS 12.6 (21G115)).

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
# source <(ng completion script)
```

Still need to work out the root cause.

Comment: Duplicate of Norbu Sonam's answer -- showing the impacting lines of .zshrc.

Comment: One feels so welcome here.